# hook_theme_registry_alter() and theme()

Tags: 7, theming

How can `hook_theme_registry_alter()` associate, for example, `theme_mymodule_image_output()` with the 'image' theme ID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As reported in the documentation, [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/6) is invoked from Drupal to allow third-party modules to alter the theme registry information returned from [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme/6).

The value returned from the implementations of `hook_theme()` is an array containing information about the different theme functions implemented by the modules (or themes).

```
function node_theme() {
  return array(
    'node' => array(
      'arguments' => array('node' => NULL, 'teaser' => FALSE, 'page' => FALSE), 
      'template' => 'node',
    ), 
    'node_list' => array(
      'arguments' => array('items' => NULL, 'title' => NULL),
    ), 
    'node_search_admin' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
    ), 
    'node_filter_form' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL), 
      'file' => 'node.admin.inc',
    ), 
    'node_filters' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL), 
      'file' => 'node.admin.inc',
    ), 
    'node_admin_nodes' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL), 
      'file' => 'node.admin.inc',
    ), 
    'node_add_list' => array(
      'arguments' => array('content' => NULL), 
      'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
    ), 
    'node_form' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL), 
      'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
    ), 
    'node_preview' => array(
      'arguments' => array('node' => NULL), 
      'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
    ), 
    'node_log_message' => array(
      'arguments' => array('log' => NULL),
    ), 
    'node_submitted' => array(
      'arguments' => array('node' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}
```

The returned array used what in my previous comment I called theme ID, and it is the same value that is passed to theme().
[node_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_theme/6) doesn't use it, but the documentation for `hook_theme()` reports that the array can use the `function` index to report which function needs to be called as theme function.

A module implementing `hook_theme_registry_alter()` should use the following code to change the function that is invoked when `theme('image')` is called.

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  if (isset($theme_registry['image'])) {
    $theme_registry['image']['function'] = 'theme_mymodule_image_output';
  }
}
```

When a module alters the theme registry using that code, any call to `theme('image', ...)` will not invoke [theme_image()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_image/6) anymore, but it will invoke the function defined from that module.
To notice that it is not necessary to name the function `theme_mymodule_image_output()`; the code would work the same if the function is renamed `mymodule_image_output()` and the code of `mymodule_theme_registry_alter()` is accordingly changed. I usually use the prefix `theme_` to make clear the function is a theme function.