# Unable to override theme function

Tags: theming

I am trying to override the 'link_field' theme function in the Link module. I've put this function in my template.php of my active theme and have cleared the cache, but its not overriding. What am I doing wrong?

```
 function tma_corp_link_field($vars) {
  dpm($vars);
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'link') . '/link.css');
  $element = $vars['element'];
  // Prefix single value link fields with the name of the field.
  if (empty($element['#field']['multiple'])) {
    if (isset($element['url']) && !isset($element['title'])) {
      $element['url']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';
    }
  }

  $output = '';
  $output .= '<div class="link-field-subrow clearfix">';
  if (isset($element['title'])) {
    $output .= '<div class="link-field-title link-field-column">' .      drupal_render($element['title']) . '</div>';
  }
  $output .= '<div class="link-field-url' . (isset($element['title']) ? ' link-field-column' : '') . '">' . drupal_render($element['url']) . '</div>';
  $output .= '</div>';
  if (!empty($element['attributes']['target'])) {
    $output .= '<div class="link-attributes">' . drupal_render($element['attributes']['target']) . '</div>';
  }
  if (!empty($element['attributes']['title'])) {
   $output .= '<div class="link-attributes">' . drupal_render($element['attributes']['title']) . '</div>';
  }
  if (!empty($element['attributes']['class'])) {
   $output .= '<div class="link-attributes">' . drupal_render($element['attributes']['class']) . '</div>';
  }
  dpm($element);
  return $output; 
 }
```

Comment: Just to check, your theme is called tma_corp and is active, right ?

Comment: to add to the above comment, If this is on a node creation page, the active theme on this page will be the admin theme, so your function will need to go in your admin themes template.php

Comment: If it is on an admin page and you are using an admin theme (or if you prefer to keep your code in modules over themes), consider using hook_theme_registry_alter() in a custom module.

Comment: @Webdrips - Thanks! You were correct about it being on the admin theme, I didn't think about that and the hook_theme_registry_alter did the trick. Please create an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to help keep your theme files cleaner, the preference is to place theme overrides in a custom module. This allows you to switch themes without having copy, paste, and rename a bunch of code.

Also this may be your only choice if, for example, you're trying to override a theme function that's being called from an admin page, you have an admin theme enabled, and you don't want to bother with creating a subtheme for your admin theme.

The workaround here is to use `hook_theme_registry_alter()`; see [this page on Drupal Stack Exchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/hook-theme-registry-alter-and-theme).

Comment: Who's preference?

Comment: I share the author's opinion here: https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/avoiding-templatephp-doom-or-overriding-theme-functions-modules